# Convex set of huber's contamination model

Tags: robust, convex, huber

In the celebrated [Huber's robust estimation paper](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-mathematical-statistics/volume-35/issue-1/Robust-Estimation-of-a-Location-Parameter/10.1214/aoms/1177703732.full), he considered the following model
$x_i \sim (1-\epsilon) P_\theta + \epsilon G$ where $P_\theta$ is assume to be standard normal. Under this model, data is contaminated by some unknown distribution $G$ with probability of $\epsilon$. The goal for the original paper is to estimate $\theta$ robust to the contamination from Q. Considering $G$ to be all possible probability density function, is the set of functions $(1-\epsilon)P_\theta + \epsilon G$ convex?

I understand that the space of all cdfs is convex so $G$ by itself is a convex set. What about this mixture of $P_\theta$ and $G$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This space is indeed convex.

Using the definition for what is a convex set, for any $t \in [0,1]$,let $G_1,G_2$ be two probabilities, we want to know whether the following distribution is in Huber's contamination model:
$$t ((1-\varepsilon)P_{\theta}+\varepsilon G_1)+(1-t)((1-\varepsilon)P_{\theta}+\varepsilon G_2).$$
This is equal to
$$(1-\varepsilon)P_{\theta}+\varepsilon (tG_1+(1-t)G_2)$$
which is indeed again a corrupted Gaussian distribution with outlier probability $tG_1+(1-t)G_2$.

Comment: Thanks! If this is a convex set, the solution to $\theta$ should be simple by treating $G$ as nuance. What is the significance of the robust estimator? Is that the inference for $\theta$?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Could you reformulate ?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. So the goal of the model is to estimate $\theta$. I understand that for a fixed $\theta$, this is a convex set. However, if we need to estimate $\theta$, i.e., for all $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$ and $G$ being all possible probability density function, is the set $(1-\epsilon) P_\theta + \epsilon G$ still convex?

Comment: It depends of the set $M=\{P_\theta, \theta \in \mathbb{R}\}$. If $M$ is convex, then yes $(1-\varepsilon)P_\theta+\varepsilon G$ is convex (translation and dilatation of convex set).

Comment: I see. So if $M$ is the exponential family, then it should be convex. What if we also need to estimate all, i.e. $\epsilon$, $\theta$ and $G$? I felt like it becomes a mixture normal problem that is not convex any more.

Comment: G is not fixed, it is whatever, so in fact if you allow any epsilon, $(1-\varepsilon)P_\theta+\varepsilon G$ can be any distribution. So this is the whole space, this is convex... Now, if you restrict to search only $\varepsilon <1/2$ then this becomes a very hard problem indeed. Without talking about convexity, It is not even identifiable (because G can be whatever).

Comment: Thanks again. Why restricting $\epsilon < 1/2$ introduces the identifiability issue? I thought it should not be a problem since $P_\theta$ has a parametric form (let's assume single mode such as the normal distribution). In fact, we need to discretize $G$ when estimating it, i.e., $G(x) = \sum_{j=1}^M w_j \delta_{x \in (\pi_{j-1}, \pi_j]}$ where $\pi_j, j=1,\ldots,M$ are the grid points. Would this introduce more issues?

Comment: No you misunderstood what I said, restricting to $\varepsilon <1/2$ may make things identifiable (because then the majority of the information is about P).  What you are asking when estimating $G, \varepsilon, P_\theta$ at the same time is very hard and already only estimating $\varepsilon, P_\theta$ is hard and most of the time $\varepsilon$ is supposed known in the litterature. I can't help you for such a difficult problem.